# Google Sheets YouTube API Apps Script issue

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I went through this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hoCht3kzN7s

Repeating every single step. Too bad it ended with a error message.

The original code from tutorial (that I've written myself) is attached below.
And in the video it works for her well. It does debug error me though.

can you tell me what's wrong in this code? I can't find the exact issue, ignoring doesn't help. API's are added with no problem.

I just want to get automatically working code for google sheets to get the following info from any YouTube video link: publishing date, views, likes, comments.

Can you give some free-to-use code-mockups for that? Or code with a explanation for beginners like me. Error message is:

> Syntax error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument
> list line: 63 file: Code.gs

Lines 62-64:

```
function writeStats_(currentStats, dataRange) {   
  let newDataRange = dataRange.offset (0, 1, currentStats.length, currentStats[0]length).setValues(currentStats); 
}
```

my code (that I have been writing watching that video) is:

```js
function onOpen() {
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi;
  ui.createMenu('YouTube'.addItem('getStats').addToUi());
}

function getstats() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  //Get range without the header row
  let dataRange = sheet.getDataRange().offset(1, 0, sheet.getLastRow() - 1);
  let values = dataRange.getValues();
  let videoUrls = [];
  let currentStats = [];
  
  extractVideoUrl_(values, videoUrls);
  getCurrentStats_(videoUrls, currentStats);
  writeStats_(currentStats, dataRange);
  doFormatting_(sheet);
}

function extractVideoUrl_(values, videoUrls) {
  values.forEach(function(video)   { 
    videoUrls.push(video[0]);
  });
  return videoUrls;
}

function getCurrentStats_(videoUrls, currentStats) {
  videoUrls.forEach(function(videoUrl) {
    if(videoUrl != "") {
      let videoID = extractVideoIdFromUrl_(videoUrl);
      let detailsResponse = getVideoDetails_(videoId)

      let title = detailsResponse.items[0].snippet.title;
      let publishDate = detailsResponse.items[0].snippet.publishedAt;
      let publishDateFormatted = new Date(publishDate);
      let views = detailsResponse.items[0].statistics.viewCount;
      let likes = detailsResponse.items[0].statistics.likeCount;
      let comments = detailsResponse.items[0].statistics.commentCount;

      currentStats.push([title, pubslishDataFormatted, views, comments, likes]);
    }
  });
  return currentStats;
}

function extractVideoIdFromUrl_(url) {
  let videoId = url.split('v=')[1];
  let ampersandPosition = videoId.indexOf('&');
  if(ampersandPosition != -1) {
    videoId = videoId.substring(0, ampersandPosition);
  }
  return videoId;
}

function getVideoDetails_(videoId) {
  let part = "snippet,statistics";
  let response = YouTube.Videos.list(part, {'id': videoId});
  return response;
}

function writeStats_(currentStats, dataRange) {
  let newDataRange = dataRange.offset (0, 1, currentStats.length, currentStats[0]length).setValues(currentStats);
}

function doFormatting_(sheet) {
  sheet.getRange('D:F').setNumberFormat('#,###');
  sheet.getRange('C:C').setNumberFormat('dd.mm.yyyy');
  sheet.getDataRange().offset(1, 0, sheet.getLastRow() -1).sort({column: 4, ascending: false});
}
```

Comment: In order to avoid your current error of `Syntax error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list line: 63 file: Code.gs`, please modify `currentStats[0]length` to `currentStats[0].length`.

Comment: Thank you! Not it says the following: 3:21:41 AM Notice Execution started
3:21:42 AM Error 
TypeError: "YouTube".addItem is not a function
onOpen @ Code.gs:3

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `Thank you! Not it says the following: 3:21:41 AM Notice Execution started 3:21:42 AM Error TypeError: "YouTube".addItem is not a function onOpen @ Code.gs:3`, I thought that your 1st issue was resolved. About this new issue, in this case, I think that it is required to modify `ui.createMenu('YouTube'.addItem('getStats').addToUi());`. You can see the detail of the custom menu at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus .